# When publishing a maven package with GitHub Actions, is it possible to generate a package description automatically?

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

I'm using GitHub actions to publish a jar package created via maven. The resulting package is published on GitHub packages. It works well, but the "About this package" text just says: "No description available yet." I was expecting that this about text would come from the `<description>` information in the Maven `pom.xml` file, but that doesn't seem to be used.

Is there a way to populate the "About this package" text automatically, either from the release notes, the maven POM-file, via some special file in the git repository, or in some other way?

If you want to see the code and setup, the package in question is here: https://github.com/acmsigsoft/submission-checker/packages/429835

Comment: Asked the same question here, no answer though... https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/10694